# when using from file import function, how can the importing file be modified to give a desired output without modifying the imported file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

File 1

```
def multiply():
    x = raw_input('enter the number')
    y = x*4
```

File 2

```
from file1 import multiply
```

how do i make the value of `x = 4` and hence the result `(4*4) = 16` without user input being implemented when running `file2`?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with functions being in two different files, they could just as well be in the same module and the problem still exists. There is a hackey, terrible way of achieving this, but why don't you just write a function that takes a parameter instead of input from the user?

Comment: So are you essentially trying to *replace* the line in File 1 where it says `x = raw_input('enter the number')` with `x = 4`? I don't think that's possible with functions because the variables are local, meaning that they can't be accessed outside of the function. If you used *classes*  instead, you would be able to override it after inheriting the class in the other file.

Comment: You can't just modify `file1`? You can make it so it takes an argument `x` that defaults to `None`, and if the function doesn't receive a valid value for `x` it asks the user for one. `def multiply(x=None):`

Answer (score 2):

There is a straightforward albeit hackey way of achieving what you want. I recommend against it. It is fundamentally a poor design choice, but here it is:

```
def multiply():
    x = int(raw_input())
    print x * 4

import sys
import io
def force_stdin(f, force_input):
    stdin = sys.stdin
    sys.stdin = io.StringIO(unicode(force_input))
    f()
    sys.stdin = stdin

force_stdin(multiply, '4')
```

Output:

```
16
```

Comment: Good answer. Hopefully, OP won't use it ;)

Comment: Yes, I can only hope.